# Reinitialize custom debian source list

Tags: debian, package-management

I just added new package into `./dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages` .. how do I reinitialize it? I assume I have to reinitialize it because when I do `apt update` I dont see package I just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
reprepro includedeb distro pool/main/a/package.deb
```